# How to implement bullet points in a JTextPane?

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, bulletedlist

I have a `JTextPane` with a `StyledDocument` and `RTFEditorKit` implemented.

How can I add bullet points (preferrably multi-level ones) onto the `JTextPane`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out doing this:

```
HTMLEditorKit.InsertHTMLTextAction bulletAction = new HTMLEditorKit.InsertHTMLTextAction("Bullet", "<li> </li>", HTML.Tag.BODY, HTML.Tag.UL);
```

Comment: still glitchy though...text never leaves the <ul>

Comment: How about your rendering? I'm having similar issues and used a similar solution but the rendering is terrible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17522022/jtextpane-bullet-with-htmleditorkit-list-not-rendering-correctly-unless-i-do-s

Answer (score 3):

Well it does not have built in support for this, however here is a great link with tutorial on creating bulleted and numbered lists in `JTextPane` and `JEditorPane`s:

- [Bullets and Numberings in the JEditorPane/JTextPane.](http://java-sl.com/bullets_numberings.html)

Comment: Dont think this works with JTextPane, b/c many of the methods, such as getParagraphElement, dont exist.

Comment: if you use `textPane.getDocument().getParagraphElement(int pos)` it will work, see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/text/StyledDocument.html)

Comment: ah thanks! I bet ill have to modify some methods, but it seems simple enough!

Comment: Do you know how to fix the 'ElementNameAttribute' and 'ListEditorKit' errors, which both dont exist according to netbeans.

Comment: @user1332495 I'd suggest just downloading the Jar file directly, extract its contents using 7zip, and then goto src->articles->list folder all is there including missing classes: http://java-sl.com/download/bullets_numberings.jar as ListEditorKit etc are there own made classes and don't come with the JDK

Comment: There are still 2 errors, the ElementNameAttribute (which i assume to replace with 'this', and the 'insert' method

Comment: still need to figure out how to fix/find the method for 'insert'

Comment: @user1332495 please show the line which contains the insert which is giving problems

Comment: where is this? have you changed the code in anyway? I.e using a TextPane and not texteditor? I copied and pasted the code to my IDE and it ran first time

Comment: I am using a TextPane, if that makes a difference

Comment: It doesnt I just checked. I change the `extends JTextEditor` to `extends JTextPane` and no error, I'm afraid something has went wrong, 1st get the application working alone in its own project before adding it to yours. As I said I cant help anymore, I have no problems with running the code

Comment: I get this error when doing that:

    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: documenteditor001.ListDocument cannot be cast to javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but what I have done is:

```
private final Action ORDERED_LIST_ACTION = new HTMLEditorKit.InsertHTMLTextAction("ORDERED-LIST", "<ol> </ol>", HTML.Tag.BODY, HTML.Tag.OL);
private final Action UNORDERED_LIST_ACTION = new HTMLEditorKit.InsertHTMLTextAction("UNORDERED-LIST", "<ul> </ul>", HTML.Tag.BODY, HTML.Tag.UL);
private final Action LIST_ITEM_ACTION = new HTMLEditorKit.InsertHTMLTextAction("BULLET", "<li> </li>", HTML.Tag.UL, HTML.Tag.LI, HTML.Tag.OL, HTML.Tag.LI);
```

When I have list creation and bullet creation as separate actions the interaction seems to work much better.