# bulleted list in JtextPane in Swings

Tags: java, swing

Functionality is "whenever i press a button a bullet should appear in textpane", but problem i am facing is whenever i am writing a text in front of bullet and then pressing the button two bullets are appearing instead of one.

I am pasting code for your reference.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;


import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument;

import javax.swing.text.html.HTML;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit;


public class HTMLDocumentEditor {
    JTextPane textPane;

    AbstractDocument doc;
    public JPanel createPanel(){
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        HTMLDocument document = new HTMLDocument();
        textPane = new JTextPane(document);
        HTMLEditorKit.InsertHTMLTextAction bulletAction = new HTMLEditorKit.
        InsertHTMLTextAction("Bullets", "<li> </li>",HTML.Tag.BODY,HTML.Tag.UL);
        JButton bulletButton = new JButton(bulletAction);
        bulletButton.setText("Bullet");
        textPane.setContentType("text/html");
        panel.add(bulletButton,BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textPane);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        panel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        HTMLEditorKit editorKit = new HTMLEditorKit();
        textPane.setEditorKit(editorKit);

        return panel;
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        HTMLDocumentEditor edit = new HTMLDocumentEditor();
        frame.add(edit.createPanel());

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event dispatch thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526992/how-to-implement-bullet-points-in-a-jtextpane/11527085#11527085) similar answer.

Comment: This is actually not the same question, the other is with RTFEditor and this is with HtmlEditor. Subtle but important difference unfortunately :(